# An Easy Way to Consume a Twitter Search Feed With ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, atom-feed

Anyone have an pointers on an easy way to consume a search.twitter.com feed with ASP.Net? I tried using the RSSToolKit, but it doesn't provide anything for parsing the  and other tags in the feed.

For example: I want to parse this feed: http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=c%23 and make it appear on a page just like it does in the twitter search results (links and all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what sort of hammer you prefer, you could use:

- An XSL transform, easy if you know
  XSL, painful if you've never used it
- Load it into an XmlDocument or
  XPathDocument, then iterate the nodes you want
- Put it into an XmlDataSource and
  then bind that to a repeater

Many other options too, they're just some of my preferred hammers

Comment: I guess my hammer of choice will be using an xmldoc. Thanks.